# kotlin: accessing class variable from multiple launch block

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Good day,

I learned kotlin some months ago, but I'm totally new to coroutines. I can't post my full code here, but basically I want to access a variable inside a class.

Here is some codes to help understanding my question:

```
class CertainClass {

   var someVar: Boolean = false;

   suspend fun doIt(){
     //...

     certainScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        someFun2()
     }
     

     certainScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        someFun1()
     }


     //...
   }
    

    //....

   suspend fun someFun1(){
     //...

     someVar = true

     //...
   }

    //...

   suspend fun someFun2(){

     while(earth.exists()) {
         
         print(someVar); // Here is my problem, this always print false, even thought someVar was set to true...

         if (someVar == true){
            // Do something nasty...
         }

         delay(1000)
     }

   }

}
```

What did I miss...?

Comment: You probably have a race condition and the property hasn’t actually been changed by the time you think it has. Not enough code has been shared to be able to tell.

Comment: do you mean this code supposed to work? I'm pretty sure the `someVar ` is not set somewhere else, but I will check for it again later

Comment: It’s very little code but I don’t see any problems with what I see. You haven’t shown enough that I could tell you what order you should expect code to execute in. There are no surprising differences in the way suspend functions and coroutines access properties.